# For a linear map $\theta: V \rightarrow W$ show $\{u\in V:\theta(u)=\theta(v)\}=v+\text{ker } \theta$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a linear map $\theta:V \rightarrow W$ show $\{u\in V:\theta(u)=\theta(v)\}=v+\text{ker } \theta$  where $v\in V$

So far I have that 
\begin{align}
\{u \in V : \theta(u)=\theta(v)\}&=\{u\in V:\theta(u-v)=0\}\\
&=\{u \in V : u-v \in \text{ker }\theta\}
\end{align}

but I don't know where to go from here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Notice that $u = v + u - v $.

Comment: Have you ever heard of equivalence class?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, could you just confirm is this is right? The set becomes $\{v + (u-v): u-v\in \text{ker }\theta\} = v + \text{ker }\theta$

Comment: Yup, this is it. Try to search on equivalence classes. What you have found is a class, such that  $u - v \in \text{ker}\  \theta$